# Zero-dimensional numpy.ndarray : only element is a 2D array : how to access it?

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, numpy

I have imported a Matlab *.mat file using scipy.io and trying to extract the 2D data from it. There are several arrays inside, and when I am trying to get them I got stuck at the last operation.

The data looks like the image below. When I try to index it: *IndexError: too many indices for array*

I have googled to the point that it looks like a single valued tuple, where the only element is my array. This in principle must be indexable, but it doesn't work. The *type(data)* returns <*class 'numpy.ndarray'*>

So the question is: how do I get my 2D array out of this data structure?

```
    data[0] # Doesn't work.
```

[image: array in question]

Comment: `array[0]`? Without telling us what you have tried, it's hard to say where your problem might lie.

Comment: Could you add an example to generate a similar matrix or at least how you are trying to retrieve the data? What does it outputs if you execute `my_array.shape`?

Comment: If I knew how to generate a similar matrix, I would've known the answer. I have found a way around though, some voodoo coding, I will post the reply asap.

Comment: Short answer is `data.item()`.

Answer (score 8):

A search on `loadmat` should yield many SO questions that will help you pick apart this result.  `loadmat` has to translate MATLAB objects into Python/numpy approximations.

```
data = io.loadmat(filename)
```

should produce a dictionary with some cover keys and various data keys.  `list(data.keys())` to identify those.

```
x = data['x']
```

should match the `x` variable in the MATLAB workspace.  It could be a 2d, order F array, corresponding to a MATLAB matrix.

It could be (n,m) object dtype array, corresponding to a MATLAB cell.

It could be a structured array, where the field names correspond to a MATLAB `struct` attributes.

In your case it looks like you have a 0d object dtype array.  The shape is `()`, an  empty tuple (1d has (n,) shape, 2d has (n,m) shape, etc).  You can pull the element out of a () array with:

```
 y[()]
 y.item()
```

The `[()]` looks odd, but it's logical.  For a 1d array `y[1]` can be written as `y[(1,)]`.  For 2d, `y[1,2]` and `y[(1,2)]` are the same.  The indexing tuple should match the number of dimensions.  Hence a `()` can index a () shape array.

Comment: This behavior of 0-d arrays numpy is extremely unintuitive (and hard to discover). This could be fixed by changing the `IndexError` message for 0-D arrays to `IndexError: …; Use x[()] or x.item() to extract the value from a 0-D array.`

Answer (score 1):

After some voodoo coding I have found a funny way to solve this:

The initial *data* is the zero-dimensional  where the only element is the 2D array. The way to get this element out apparently is:

```
    z = data.item()[()][0]
    print(z)
```

The final result is below I got my 2D array:

[image: Workable 2D data]

Comment: Are you telling yourself that your own answer doesn't work?