# Extracting array from dictionary value

Tags: python, arrays

I am using Python, trying to extract a matrix of distances from a .mat file. It comes in the form of a dictionary "dists" which is the following

```
print(dists)
```

[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5PA5.png)

I want to get the matrix as an array: I tried extracting the value (Python allows it to be converted to an array) but I can't take only the array out, since it says it is 0-dimensional.

```
arr = np.array(dists[0].values())
print(type(arr))
print(arr)
print(arr[0])
```

[image][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fa0Jv.png)

It looks like the array is 0-dimensional of the form ([[ ... ]]). How can I extract the 2D matrix?

I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51149865/zero-dimensional-numpy-ndarray-only-element-is-a-2d-array-how-to-access-it) but couldn't figure out how to apply it to my problem.  I tried `arr[()]` but it still thinks `arr` is a dictionary value rather than an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you need to change `dict_values()` to `list`. I hope this example can help you.

```py
import numpy as np
dishes = {'eggs': 2, 'sausage': 1, 'meat': 1, 'spam': np.ones((3,3))}
print(dishes.values())
arr = list(dishes.values())
print(arr)
print(arr[-1])
```

Terminal Output:

```
dict_values([2, 1, 1, array([[1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.]])])
[2, 1, 1, array([[1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.]])]
[[1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1.]]
```